# Using present continuous passive (is being) for describing repeating (undesirable) actions

Tags: tenses, sentence, passive-voice

I am trying to understand if it is possible to build sentences in such a way, I feel like I have seen somewhere using this tense in the same way I am trying to use it.

Is it possible to use Present Continuous Passive for describing (undesirable)  behaviour of something that began in the past and I am still dealing with?

For example, this program has began to crash (and it is still crashing).
Is it possible to say in a case like this

> Program is being crashing when I click button.

Or it is better to use present simple

> Program crashes when I click button.

Comment: No. 'The program often / regularly / consistently /  inevitably crashes when I click on the button.'

Comment: The bank is being eaten away by the river.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Is being crashing* is not English. The passive progressive/continuous is *is being crashed*, the active progressive/continuous is *is crashing*.

You don't want a passive in this case: *crash* in this sense is an intransitive verb, so it cannot be cast in the passive.

But an active progressive/continuous is perfectly acceptable. The main difference between "The program crashes when I click the button" and "The program is crashing when I click the button" is that the version with the simple present *tends* to be understood as a more or less permanent characteristic, while that with the progressive *tends* to be understood as a temporary characteristic--a recent development, for instance, which you at least hope can be reversed. But in this case that's a fairly weak implication, perhaps because we all take pretty much for granted that temporary misbehavior is more or less a permanent characteristic of computers!

Comment: Sorry, I have mistaken, I mean `is being crashed`

Comment: @CROSP As I say, don't use it; programs are not crashed by outside forces, they crash all by themselves (unless you have specific evidence to the contrary). So what you want is "the program crashes" or "the program is crashing".

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully these four valid sentences will help you understand the tense you have in mind:

> The program keeps crashing because you didn't allocate enough memory.
>
> Not allocating enough memory can kill a program.
>
> The program keeps getting killed because you didn't allocate enough
>   memory.
>
> The program **is always being killed** because you didn't allocate enough
>   memory.